# Stretch a background image in IE8

Tags: css

I'm trying to stretch a background image to 100% width and height of the parent div. background-size is not supported in IE8 of-course. I tried the following code but it's not working.

```
.box:before {
    background: url(images/body_background2.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use a `<img>` with `position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;` and negative `z-index`. There's unfortunately no way to implement this behavior in IE 8 using only CSS.

See the following article for further information: [How Do you Stretch a Background Image in a Web Page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm).

If you wish to use an image as a background for a given `<div>` try the following approach:

```
<div class="fullbackground">
    <img class="fullbackground" src="yourImageSrc" />
</div>
```

```
.fullbackground{
    position:relative;
}
img.fullbackground{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; /* alternative: right:0; */
    height:100%; /* alternative: bottom:0; */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works nice for full page. But I'm trying to apply only to one div in the middle of the page.

Comment: Cool, I bumped in to that article many times without noticing the later part.

Comment: @user1157575: See the later part of the article ;) - I updated my answer. You don't need `class=fullbackground` on your container if the `<div>` is already positioned.

Comment: just as a side note, if you want the image to be responsive (i.e. not squish the image when the page's width is less than the images width) then just add `min-width: {whatever-width-the-image-is}` the same goes for the height

Answer (score 3):

I use this article often to do my full screen backgrounds :)

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Doesn´t make it a lesser solution ;) so +1

Comment: My question wasn't for the full page, just for one div.

Comment: Hmm? So what? You should be able to use the same technique.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `AlphaImageLoader` filter and setting the `sizingMethod` to `scale` seems to do the trick according to [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<img class="fullscreen" src="fullscreen.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
img.fullscreen {
  border:     0;
  height:     auto;
  left:       0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width:  1024px;
  padding:    0;
  position:   fixed;
  top:        0;
  width:      100%;
  z-index:    -1001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill.  This is a nice plugin another member of my team came across for the same issue.

Once you have the script included into your solution, add the following line into the relevant CSS class along with any other sizing/positioning attributes you may wish to add.

`-ms-behavior: url(/scripts/backgroundsize.min.htc);`

We have this implemented for full width images and widget backgrounds and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

This ([demo](http://codepen.io/johan/full/AdpCB)) does the trick (digestable version of css-only technique #2 from http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
<div class="background-size_cover">
  <img src="images/body_background2.png">
</div>
```

and

```
.background-size_cover {
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
}
.background-size_cover img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You'll want to make sure that the parent div is `overflow: hidden;` besides having whatever dimensions you want the image to get stretched to fit in.

Answer (score 0):

I combined `AlfaImageLoader` filter with css3 `background-size` and worked on all browsers. Here's what i did.

```
background : url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat ;
background-size: 100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
            (src='images/background.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
```

By the way, you need to put your background image to your wrapper div in this method.