# How do I implement a full page background without a scroll bar that works in IE8

Tags: css, html, background

I cannot remove the scroll bar on a website and keep a full page background[web site i am working on](http://www.robnold.com) I do not want to decrease the height of the image and leave a small strip at the bottom without a background. How do I implement a full page background without a scroll bar that works in IE8?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 height:100%;
width:100%
}

body{background-size: 100%;}

@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(pachs___.ttf);
}

img.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}

div.wholepage{width:100%; height:100%;border-style:solid; border-width:0px;padding:0px;}

</style>
<body>

<div class="wholepage">
<img src="images\parchment.png" class="stretch">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385566/stretch-a-background-image-in-ie8[/link]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a scroll bar, you can add `OVERFLOW: HIDDEN;` to the body & html, or you can make sure that the body's contents are absolutely positioned, thus making the body not inherit the height.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can't use background-size in IE8 as it's not supported, [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) supports it, but it's  still it's a javascript solution, so I'd stick with something simple with javascript.

In css, this is what we'd originally have to do, this may just work in IE8 with the filters attached, however to be sure, I'd stick with javascript.

```
    html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    }
```

Here's a working solution.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
```

**CSS**

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DUEsh/

Works in IE7+ (could probably get in IE6 with a fixed position shim)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want scrollbars ever, you could just add overflow: hidden; to the body;

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
  overflow: hidden;
}
```